# How do I find explicit formula of function, examine continuity and draw their graphs?

Tags: functions, continuity

Three-cylinder with height 4m and radii of the base 5, 3 and 1 m are going to put (in this order). Give an explicit formula for the following functions, you examine the functions on continuity and draw their graphs.

a)The cross-sectional area F (h) of horizontal sections of the body obtained as Function of the height h ∈ [0, 12].

b) The volume V (h) of the body of height h ∈ [0, 12].

I don't understand this example, I don't know how to start, if someone can help me I would be really thankful

Comment: Hints : The radius of the sectional area depends on the height $h$. To calculate the volume of the body, you have to add voluminas of cylinders.

Comment: When I calculate voluminas of cylinders, what is next that I need to do?

Comment: The cross-sectional area is a circle. Upto height $4$, it has radius $5$, for height $4-8$ it has radius $3$ and for height $8-12$ it has radius $1$. Use the formula $A=r^2\pi$ to calculate the area in any case. The function you get is not continous at $r=4,8$ and $12$.

Comment: How do you that exactly for height 4-8 it has radius 3?

Comment: Yes, exactly you have to write $r=3$ for $4<h\le 8$.

Comment: And depending on the height, you have to add the volumina of $1$, $2$ or $3$ cylinders.

Comment: Why I need to use formula A for what is that? And how do you that fucntion get no continous at those levels

Answer (score 1):

You put the three cylinders on top of each other (the larger ones at the bottom), like it has been done for this [wedding cake](http://s3.weddbook.com/t4/2/2/3/2230736/rustic-wedding-cake-topper-vintage-cylinder-headband-country-fall-alternative-weddings.jpg).

For question a), you go to some height $h$, and make a *horizontal* slice through the cylinder at that height. If you are at height $h$ less that $4$ m, then you slice the first cylinder, if you are at height $h$ between $4$ and $8$ m, you slice the second cylinder, and if you are at height $h$ between $8$ and $12$ m, you slice the third cylinder.

When you slice a cylinder at height $h$, you need to find the cross-sectional area of that cylinder. This area will be the same as the area of the base of the cylinder you sliced.

For question b), you need to calculate the volume of the entire structure up to height $h$.

**Edit**: Each cylinder is $4$ m, and they are stacked upon each other. This means that

- From $0$ to $4$ m, you have the big cylinder of radius $5$ m.
- From $4$ to $8$ m, you have the middle cylinder of radius $3$ m.
- From $8$ to $12$ m, you have the small cylinder of radius $1$ m.

In the picture below, I have the bases of each cylinder:

[image]

If I move up maybe $2$ m in the structure, and slice through it, then I am slicing through the big cylinder, and the cross section I will see is that of the big circle. In fact, for any height between $0$ m and $4$ m, it will be the big circle that I get as cross section, but if I move any higher, then I get either the middle circle or the small circle.

You need to write up the function $F(h)$, which is the area of the cross section at height $h$. For instance, $F(2)$ is the area of the large circle, like I explained above.

Comment: I don't understand how I can slice than

Comment: If you do some calculus it would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: @AidaBrown what exactly are you having a problem with? Do you understand what problem a) is asking for?

Comment: No, I don't understand

Comment: @AidaBrown Ok, I have tried to elaborate in my post. Do you understand it now? For instance, can you tell what $F(2)$ is from what I've written?